# Can't get cache when security protection level is set to unsafe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, appfabric

I'm testing the AppFabric cache feature in my website deployed from ASP.net MVC 4. In the web.config of my website, if I set the security level to anything except no security (**None/None**), like this

```
<securityProperties mode="Transport" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
```

then, getting cache from the method below will throw exception,

```
DataCacheFactory.GetDefaultCache()
```

Also, in the PowerShell Cache Management, I've already set the protection level to the same level (**Transport/EncryptAndSign**).
But getting cache still failed.

Exception message is as following,

**ErrorCode(ERRCA0017):SubStatus(ES0006):There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable... )**

The situation only happens in my deployed website. But if I run my website in Visual Studio debug mode, cache would response successfully no matter what the security level is set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I finally solved the tricky issue. This tough thing nearly made me contribute my 50 bounties (almost half) !

After some survey, I found the first clue,

[Security Error in APPFabric when changed the security mode from None to Transport?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc2db797-99f0-4399-a3a3-f36ff6f241c4/security-error-in-appfabric-when-changed-the-security-mode-from-none-to-transport?forum=velocity)

(Note, I can't easily google it out from some keywords, but the result I want was easily dug out from [Msdn AppFabric Cache forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=velocity). I thought google search can help me to find any answer.)

I got the same exception message as the first link. But Rahul's answer didn't work. However, Rahul's link revealed a second clue, that is, use [Tracelog.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/09/20/appfabric-cache-peeking-into-client-amp-server-wcf-communication.aspx) to track the connection problem.

From the track log in Event Viewer, I found there are some *error* events saying my server's authority isn't accessible, so I searched in the third clue, [Cache Administration PowerShell commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177.aspx) for setting permission in PowerShell.

In the third clue, thank the author, mark_og who really saved me ! You taught us how to set the permission in IIS like this,

**Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount "IIS APPPOOL\[AppPoolName]"**

it's the key answer which solves my problem !